# How to work with data returned after form submit

Tags: amp-html

I have an AMP form that calls a web service on submit, and after that, I have a JSON as result. The JSON contains data and in order to see them, I am using `amp-mustache` template in `submit-success` div. And all is working fine. I see all the data I need. 
But I am unable to access that data from outside the `submit-success` div.  Since I need to set some controls on my form that are out of `submit-success` div, I need to access the JSON result outside the`submit-success` div.
Can anybody share how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of doing it would be by saving your JSON response to a state. You can do this by using the `on` attribute of the form to set the state on the event `submit-success` as follows:

```
<form id="form123" 
      action-xhr="/formHandle" 
      method="POST"
      on="submit-success:AMP.setState({ msg : event.response.message })"
>
```

Now you can use this state to implement your control logic anywhere in your page by using it with an `amp-bind` expression. For example,

```
<p class="" [text]=" 'Response is :' + msg">
```

If you just want to perform common actions like hide, show, toggling accordion, scroll, opening a ligthbox etc., you can do this by using the corresponding AMP action inside the `on` attribute against the `submit-success` event, without having to use `amp-bind`.

Comment: This works. Now, how can I set the returned value to a PHP variable in the very same (asynchronous) post back (without a need to do another post back)?